# Change background color of the Mat-Expansion-Panel Title on click of it in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

Below is the code I am using in Angular 15 with Angular Material 14

```
<mat-nav-list role="list">
<a mat-list-item role="listitem" class="list-item-setting" id="emailTemplatesId" *ngIf="isSysAdmin"
    (click)="sideNavLink(true, $event)" matTooltip="Notification Templates" matTooltipPosition="right"
    [matTooltipDisabled]="!isCompressed" [routerLink]="['/email-notification-templates']" routerLinkActive="active"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="admin-link">
    <mat-icon class="list-item-setting">email</mat-icon>
    <span class="nowrap add-padding">Email Templates</span>
  </a>
  <a >
  <mat-accordion *ngIf="isAdmin && !isCSR">
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle [(expanded)]="panelOpenState" class="mat-elevation-z0">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title style="text-align: left;" (click)="clickNotificationMgmt($event)">
          <img src="../../../../assets/images/icon_bell.svg" alt="Notification Management">
          <span class="add-padding-to-mat-panel-header"><a class="list-item-setting add-padding"
              [routerLink]="['/notification-list']" routerLinkActive="active">Notification Management</a></span>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div>
        <mat-panel-description (click)="clickNotificationList($event)" [ngClass]="isNotificationListClicked ? 'bold' : ''"
          id="notificationListId" (click)="sideNavLink(true, $event)" class="mat-panel-description-setting"><a
            class="list-item-setting add-padding" [routerLink]="['/notification-list']"
            routerLinkActive="active">Notification List
          </a></mat-panel-description>
          </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Below is the screenshot for `Email Templates`

[image: Email Templates]

Here `Notification Management` is an Mat-Expansion-Panel - Accordion control.

How can I display the same way as `Email Templates` for `Notification Managment`, I mean with the same background color on click of it and if the user navigates away from it, then it should come back to normal state without highlighting.

**EDIT**

[image: Notification Management]

Now the whole Accordion control is changing background color. I need it only for the `Notification Management` title. How can we achieve this..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: couldn't you just add an ngClass using the `expanded` Input? 
Something like: 
`[ngClass]="{'active-panel': panelOpenState}"`

then put your background -color under .active-panel ?

Comment: @KaptainIglo - Could not follow you properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the `expanded` attribute to set `panelOpenState`. Then, how about using `panelOpenState` into an ngClass ?
Something like :

```js
<mat-expansion-panel [(expanded)]="panelOpenState" [ngClass]="{'active-panel': panelOpenState}">
```

Then just set the active-panel class in your css:

```css
.active-panel {
  background-color: /* your desired color */;
}
```

Comment: @Kaptainlglo Your Answer works partially. I need it only for the `Notification Management` title only. Modified the Question with the example screenshot. Please check..

Comment: so, you mean that you only want the header to have a different bg color? Then I would move the `[ngClass]="{'active-panel': panelOpenState}"` to `mat-expansion-panel-header`. THen, you would have to add it to every mat-expansion-panel-header

Comment: Yes, I tried moving it to header part. But it is not working..

Comment: maybe it is because of predefined styles... Have you tried:
`::ng-deep .active-panel { ...}`
To be clear: ng-deep is depecrated and should be avoided, but it may help diagnose the problem, at least...

Comment: I used like this in scss - `::ng-deep .active-panel {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}` But still it is not working.

Comment: I'd still bet on a problem of specificity... have you tried to add `!important`? or maybe try to make it in line: 
in your header, try `[style.backgroundColor]="panelOpenState?'yourColor':'yourDefaultColor'"`

Comment: With your last comment, it is working now. Thanks. Marking as Answer.